# How to make an UIImageView be centered then have its width grow or shrink to a defined percentage of the screen width?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I have this image at the bottom of my screen that is like a cartoon bubble.

[image]
I'd like it to be centered but the whole width should not be more that 70% of the screen width. The height remains untouched.

Is is possible to do that without complex calculations?

I've tried an horizontal stack view with proportional distribution, but of course that would require to perform calculations starting from the image width versus the screen width.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    background = new UIImageView
    {
        TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false,
    };
    string base64String = ImageManager.ms_instance.GetAutoEvalImageAsBase64String(this.m_currentItem.id);
    background.Image = UIImage.LoadFromData(NSData.FromArray(Convert.FromBase64String(base64String)));

    this.View.AddSubview(background);

    bubbleSpeech = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromBundle("bubble_speech.png"));
    bubbleSpeech.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

    qualif = new UIStackView
    {
        TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false,
        Axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Horizontal,
        Distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.FillProportionally,
        Alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.Center
    };

    qualif.AddArrangedSubview(new UIView());
    qualif.AddArrangedSubview(bubbleSpeech);
    qualif.AddArrangedSubview(new UIView());

    this.View.AddSubview(qualif);

    qualif.Anchor(bottom: this.View.SaferAreaLayoutGuide().BottomAnchor, leading: this.View.SaferAreaLayoutGuide().LeadingAnchor, trailing: this.View.SaferAreaLayoutGuide().TrailingAnchor/*, size: new CGSize(328f, 94f)*/);

    background.Anchor(top: this.View.SaferAreaLayoutGuide().TopAnchor, leading: this.View.SaferAreaLayoutGuide().LeadingAnchor, trailing: this.View.SaferAreaLayoutGuide().TrailingAnchor, bottom: this.View.SaferAreaLayoutGuide().BottomAnchor);
```

The Anchor helper:

```
internal static void Anchor(this UIView uIView, NSLayoutYAxisAnchor top = null, NSLayoutXAxisAnchor leading = null, NSLayoutYAxisAnchor bottom = null, NSLayoutXAxisAnchor trailing = null, UIEdgeInsets padding = default, CGSize size = default)
{
    uIView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    if (top != null)
    {
        uIView.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(top, padding.Top).Active = true;
    }

    if (leading != null)
    {
        uIView.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(leading, padding.Left).Active = true;
    }

    if (bottom != null)
    {
        uIView.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(bottom, -padding.Bottom).Active = true;
    }

    if (trailing != null)
    {
        uIView.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(trailing, -padding.Right).Active = true;
    }

    if (size.Width != 0)
    {
        uIView.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(size.Width).Active = true;
    }

    if (size.Height != 0)
    {
        uIView.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(size.Height).Active = true;
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure this can be done easily but I can't figure it at the moment.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `multiplier` to set a view's width to a percentage of another view's width:

```
        // width equals 70% of safe area width
        bubbleSpeech.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.7),
```

So your code could be:

```
    bubbleSpeech = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromBundle("bubble_speech.png"));
    bubbleSpeech.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

    // respect safe area
    let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        // constrain bottom of bubbleSpeech to bottom of safe area
        bubbleSpeech.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        // center horizontally
        bubbleSpeech.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
        // width equals 70% of safe area width
        bubbleSpeech.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.7),
        // height = 94:328 ratio to width
        bubbleSpeech.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bubbleSpeech.widthAnchor, multiplier: 94.0 / 328.0),
    ])
```

That will make the "bubble" image view 70% of the width of the view, and height (based on your commented code in your question) will have a relative ratio to the width of `94:328`.

If you don't want a relative (proportional) height, change the `heightAnchor` constraint to:

```
        bubbleSpeech.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 94.0),
```